# quicksort partition step (python)

Tags: python, quicksort, partitioning

I am trying to partition a list of ints to accomplish quicksort. My solution works fine exepct for when an element is the same as the pivot, i do not understand how to take this scenario into account in my code and every tutorial i have seen or read so far ignores this scenario. How do i take it in to account?

My code:

```
db = [55,5,23,1,412,1000,4,3,2,55]

def partition(db):
    pivot = __median_of_three(db)
    i = -1
    j = 0
    while j < len(db):
        if db[j] < pivot:
            i += 1
            temp = db[i]
            db[i] = db[j]
            db[j] = temp
        j += 1
    print(db)

def __median_of_three(db):
    values = [item for item in db if db.index(item) == 0 or db.index(item) == len(db)//2 or db.index(item) ==  len(db)-1]
    if values[0] >= values[1] and  values[0] <= values[2] or values[0] <= values[1] and  values[0] >= values[2]:
        return values[0]
    elif values[1] >= values[0] and  values[1] <= values[2] or values[1] <= values[0] and  values[1] >= values[2]:
        return values[1]
    else:
        return values[2]

partition(db)
```

current output: `[5, 23, 1, 4, 3, 2, 55, 412, 1000, 55]`

expected output `[5, 23, 1, 4, 3, 2, 55, 55, 412, 1000]`

Comment: How is `__median_of_three()` defined, what is you input and expected output?

Comment: @AChampion i edited my question

Comment: I guess you want your if condition to be <= instead of <

Comment: Why do you think your current output is incorrect? The fact that the second 55 did not end up next to the first 55 on the first partitioning is not a problem. The next partitioning on the `[412, 1000, 55]` list will move the second 55 next to the first one.